# Cannot find keyword using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

Am trying to find a certain keyword in url string like so

```
import re
test = re.match(r'coo', 'https://example.com/coo-dropped-today/', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but when test my `test` variable using `type(test)` it presents me with `<class 'NoneType'>`.

But when i run the same string through regexpal i seem to find a match as evidenced from the screenshot below

[image]

This is not a complex regex expression so am guessing regex parsers or engines don't matter.

Why i am unable to find a match in my python code?
Thank you.

Comment: `re.match` only searches at the start of the string.

Comment: You're using a `javascript` regular expression tester. Here's an online one for Python (https://pythex.org/)

Comment: @RyanWilson i know but given the fact that is a simple regular expression, my guess is it should not matter